# Intent Service, Content Provider and Loader

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

When developing android applications I use Loaders to asynchronously retrieve data from a local SQLite DB through a content provider and update the Views.

When I have to retrieve data from the Internet (i.e. JSON) I use intent services. As the download finishes a broadcast receiver is triggered and the collected data stored through a Content Provider in a local SQLite Db.

Is there any way to trigger loaders execution after the DB is updated? The first time data are downloaded from the Internet I update the UI in the broadcast receiver after having updated the DB but it would be more coherent to do that through the loader as well.

**UPDATE**

Plase notice that I would like to have an answer based on Android stardard classes (Not libraries from 3rd parties)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to trigger loaders execution after the DB is updated?

Yes, just implement the notification mechanism in the `ContentProvider`. Basically:

- in `query()`, before returning the `Cursor` call `Cursor.setNotificationUri()`
- in `insert()`, `delete()`, `update()`, notify the changes to the uri with `ContentResolver.notifyChange()`

See also this [other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24087853/913286).